# Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required. The problem I cannot solve

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

## My question :

- When I didn't use the `@MapperScan` in the Application Boot class, it has this kind of problems:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.reggie.mapper.EmployeeMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1812) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1371) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

- When I add the `@MapperScan`, the problem changes to this

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:204) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(SqlSessionDaoSupport.java:122) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:73) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44) ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

### My pom is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>reggie</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>reggie</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### My Service is

```
package com.example.reggie.service;

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.service.IService;
import com.example.reggie.entity.Employee;



public interface EmployeeService extends IService<Employee> {
}
```

### My service implementation is

```
package com.example.reggie.service.impl;

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.service.impl.ServiceImpl;
import com.example.reggie.entity.Employee;
import com.example.reggie.mapper.EmployeeMapper;
import com.example.reggie.service.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl<EmployeeMapper, Employee> implements EmployeeService {
}
```

### My controller is

```
package com.example.reggie.controller;

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.conditions.query.LambdaQueryWrapper;
import com.example.reggie.common.R;
import com.example.reggie.entity.Employee;
import com.example.reggie.service.EmployeeService;
import jakarta.annotation.Resource;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.util.DigestUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmplyeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    /**
     *
     * @param request
     * @param employee
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public R<Employee> login(HttpServletRequest request , @RequestBody Employee employee){
        String passwaord=employee.getPassword();
        passwaord=DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(passwaord.getBytes());
        LambdaQueryWrapper<Employee> queryWrapper=new LambdaQueryWrapper<>();
        queryWrapper.eq(Employee::getUsername,employee.getUsername());
         Employee emp=employeeService.getOne(queryWrapper);


         if (emp==null){
             return R.error("Failed");
         }
         if (!emp.getPassword().equals(passwaord)){
             return R.error("Failed");
         }
         if (emp.getStatus()==0){
             return R.error("Forbiidden.");
         }
         request.getSession().setAttribute("employee",emp.getId());
        return R.success(emp);
    }

}
```

I don't know why.Is this the problem between Mybaties and SpringBoot?

I hope to know that the reason of this problem.

Comment: mybatis-spring 2.0.5 does not support Spring 6. Please see the [compatibility matrix](https://mybatis.org/spring/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, and i saw the answer by ave, i realized the version maybe not been supported any more for my Java17, so i changed the mybatis-spring-boot-starter from 2.2.1 to 3.0.1. Then the problem was solved.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

check your boot class, delete`(exclude= {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` if it exists;

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@MapperScan("com.yxjiang.staservice.mapper")
public class StaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add mybatis-spring-boot-starter dependency.
2. Make sure you have two dependencies which are mybatis and
   mybatis-plus dependencies when you use mybatis-plus.

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
           <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
           <version>3.5.2</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
       </dependency>
   ```